# How do you get a Drawable object via a TypedArray when the drawable resource is a Vector Drawable?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have written a custom compound view with custom attributes. One of the custom attributes is a drawable and the file I wish to use is a Vector Drawable.

```
val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, 0, 0)
val iconDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomView_icon_drawable)
```

I keep getting a XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector

Why is this?

Comment: Is your drawable correct? Android doesn't support svgs but vector drawables. These are a bit different.

Comment: Yes - I edited this to say Vector Drawable and not SVG

Comment: Maybe try to get drawable resourceId instead using `typedArray.getResourceId(..)` and then create a Drawable instance with `ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context context, @DrawableRes int id)`?

Comment: what API level are your running?

Comment: My min is 16, but I've got the vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true setting set. Also, my parent activity is extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: so you have to use `support-vector-drawable` library and `AppCompatResources#getDrawable()` method

Comment: Using AppCompatResources#getDrawable worked where ContextCompat#getDrawable did not, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved.

I needed to do the following:

```
val drawableResId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomView_icon_drawable, -1);
val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), drawableResId)
```

Credit to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) and [creck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3479154/creck) for the solution.

Answer (score 17):

#### Support library

Vector drawables are supported since Android 4.4 (API 20). Therefore, if your minimum API level (`minSdkVersion`) in **build.gradle** file  is set to less than 20, make sure you are using Support Library.

To enable support library, add following line into your app-level **build.gradle**:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

#### Custom attributes definition

Define your attribute in *attrs.xml* as type of reference:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
    <attr name="icon_drawable" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

#### Get an instance of drawable

Lastly, to be able to get an instance of specified drawable in your .xml layout file, get a drawable resource ID and using support class `ContextCompat` create the instance of this Drawable

```java
final int drawableResId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomView_icon_drawable, -1);
final Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), drawableResId)
```

Comment: I'm using the support library since my min API is 16. 
I tried the last method of using the ContextCompat but still no luck.

I have a vector drawable file named "ic_close.xml" in my res/drawable folder. 

In my view xml I have the following line:
app:icon_drawable="@drawable/ic_close"

Not sure what's going on.